# How can i MS SQL Script version-control Like TFS?

Tags: sql, tfs, version-control

How can I mange SQL script changes, way of TFS code mange and can see difference of in Table or procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Hi İ advise this product if your omployers can buy (it has free trial):
https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/index

You can create and use Visual Studio database project too...
Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272677(v=vs.103).aspx

Also check:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4904/using-source-control-with-sql-server-management-studio/